# Python doesn't detect my unittest

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have following code snippet -

```
import unittest

class SimpleWidgetTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print 'setup'
    def method_test(self):
        print 'test method'
    def tearDown(self):
        print 'tear down'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Output -

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

test method name should start with `test`. Replace `method_test` to `test_method`, and try again.

From [unittest documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#basic-example):

> A testcase is created by subclassing unittest.TestCase. The three
>   individual tests are defined with methods whose names start with the
>   letters test. This naming convention informs the test runner about
>   which methods represent tests.